# AWS Lambda not receiving Content-Type

Tags: flask, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, zappa

I'm experimenting with [zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa) in order to deploy a Flask application to API Gateway + Lambda Proxy.

However, I'm not receiving the `Content-Type` header in my application, not even as lowercased as I've seen in other answers.

Do I need to configure anything specific to this header? Other headers get passed along to my application with no configuration necessary, for instance:

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    -H "Authorization: this-reaches-lambda" \
    -H "MyCustomHeader: this-reaches-lambda" \
    -d "username=myUsername&password=myPassword" \
    "https://myurl.myregion.amazonaws.com/api/"
```

These are the headers I'm receiving in lambda:

```
[1524670029998] Content-Length: 52
[1524670029998] Accept: */*
[1524670029998] Authorization: this-reaches-lambda
[1524670029998] Cloudfront-Is-Tablet-Viewer: false
[1524670029998] Cloudfront-Viewer-Country: BR
[1524670029998] Host: myurl.amazonaws.com
[1524670029998] User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
[1524670029998] Via: 2.0 mycloudfronturl.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
[1524670029998] X-Amz-Cf-Id: Kws-G0M3QPyOZwTOCkP7psJi5Cf5B8ZVRd9luBjV0dOTFhYNVBtedQ==
[1524670029998] X-Amzn-Trace-Id: Root=1-5ae09e4d-cf432adedfa115383616168e
[1524670029998] X-Forwarded-For: myip, otherIp
[1524670029998] X-Forwarded-Port: 443
[1524670029998] X-Forwarded-Proto: https
[1524670029998] Cloudfront-Forwarded-Proto: https
[1524670029998] Cloudfront-Is-Desktop-Viewer: true
[1524670029998] Cloudfront-Is-Mobile-Viewer: false
[1524670029998] Cloudfront-Is-Smarttv-Viewer: false
[1524670029998] MyCustomHeader: this-reaches-lambda
```

Comment: Probably not related since your example uses the correct casing, but I've been bitten by this [1] bug before when using "content-type" (all lower case) [1] https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/1188